# Taking 'snapshots' of big Objects

Tags: java, oop, hash, concurrency, tree

I'm facing the following issue. One Thread is building and updating a Tree Object. To validate the Tree it is required to calculate the hash of that tree. So a second Thread calculates the hash of that tree continuously.

Now I got the following problem: That tree is about 300mb in size and I wanna ensure that the Tree doesn't change while the hash is calculated, like taking a snapshot and calculate the hash of it.

My guess is I have the following two options:

1. Blocking writing to the Tree while the hash is calculated.
   (not ideal, because the calculations takes quite some time)
2. Taking a 'snapshot' by copying that object. And then calculate the hash. 
   (also not very good because another 300mb of memory would be required)

Is there a common trick or a pattern for taking 'snapshots' of big objects without just copying them?

(My guess is that this takes profounded changes to the tree object, but I'm grateful for every tip.)

Thanks in advance,
flxh

PS: I don't know if it matters for that question but I am using Java (1.8)

Comment: Why don't you have the hash always fresh? Calculate it on every operation in a cheap way, incrementally.

Comment: Scala and Clojure have immutable data structures. You could use an immutable tree (which, when you add or remove nodes, returns a new tree, which references the old one and share most of the memory). This is a profound change, but you could use their existing collections. The best solution would be @Magnamag's, then either immutable data structures or blocking writing while calculating the hash.

Comment: @flxh Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324725/what-does-it-mean-for-a-hash-function-to-be-incremental for incremental hash definition and links to papers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should neither block while calculating a new hash nor copying or taking snapshots of the whole tree, especially if the tree takes about 300 mb of memory.

Instead, I'd take another approach. I'd use an incremental hash function. I'm not an expert in these matters, but the best one I know so far is Murmur3F from [greenrobot common](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenrobot-common/blob/master/hash-functions.md) utility library. Please check their samples.

`Murmur3F` lets you call its `update()` method many times. Then you call `getValue()` to get the actual hash value. And you can do this many times. 
So I wouldn't recalculate the hash for the whole tree in a separate thread each time it's modified. Using that Murmur3F hash implementation, I'd use the `update()` method on every update to the tree and `getValue()` on tree's `getHash()`, for instance.